# Formation of Teams in Permutation and Combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, binomial-theorem

***A class has $n$ students , we have to form a team of the students including at least two and also excluding  at least two students. The number of ways of forming the team is***

My Approach : To include at least two students the required ways is

C($n$, $2$) $+$ C($n$,$3$) $+$ C($n$,$4$)...........$+$C($n$,$n-2$) 
But I am not understanding how to calculate the number of ways of excluding at least two students with this..............

Please help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation that the number of students selected is at least $2$ and at most $n - 2$ is correct, as is your answer.  We can use the Binomial Theorem to obtain a closed form.

The Binomial Theorem states that 
$$(x + y)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{n - k}y^k$$
We can find 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}$$
by substituting $1$ for both $x$ and $y$, which yields
$$2^n = (1 + 1)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}1^{n - k}1^k = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}$$
Comparing this expression with your answer 
$$\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{3} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n - 3} + \binom{n}{n - 2} = \sum_{k = 2}^{n - 2} \binom{n}{k}$$
we have 
$$\sum_{k = 2}^{n - 2} \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} - \left[\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{n - 1} + \binom{n}{n}\right]$$
Since 
$$\binom{n}{0} = \binom{n}{n} = 1$$
and 
$$\binom{n}{1} = \binom{n}{n - 1} = n$$
we obtain
$$\sum_{k = 2}^{n - 2} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n - 2n - 2$$

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^n$ possible teams altogether, and there are

$\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{n-1}=2n$ teams with $1$ or $n-1$ students and $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{n}=2$ teams with $0$ or $n$ students;

so there are $2^n-2n-2$ teams including at least 2 students and excluding at least 2 students.

Answer (score 0):

As team should consist of at least 2 and at most $(n – 2)$ students out of $n$ students, so required number of ways = 2 students or 3 students ........or $(n – 3)$ students or $(n – 2)$ students.
$$
\implies\text{ number or ways }= {_nC_2} + {_nC_3} + {_nC_4} + \ldots + {_nC}_{n – 3} + {_n}C_{n – 2} \ldots\label{1}\tag{I}
$$
\begin{split}
{_n}C_0 + {_n}C_1 + {_n}C_2 + {_n}C_3 + \ldots + & {_n}C_{n – 2} + {_n}C_{n – 1} + {_n}C_n  = 2n\\
\Downarrow\\
\implies {_n}C_2 + {_n}C_3 + \ldots + {_n}C_{n – 2}  &= 2n – {_n}C_0 – {_n}C_1 – {_n}C_{n – 1} –  {_n}C_n\\
\implies {_n}C_2 + {_n}C_3 + \ldots + {_n}C_{n – 2}  &= 2n – 1 – n – n – 1\\
\end{split}
$$
\implies {_n}C_2 + {_n}C_3 + \ldots + {_n}C_{n – 2}  = 2n – 2n – 2  \ldots\label{2}\tag{II}
$$
Substituting \eqref{2} in \eqref{1},
$$
\text{Number of ways }= 2n – 2n – 2 
$$
Hence, number of ways of forming a team: (1) $2n – 2n – 2$

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please use Latex. Learn latex from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).